# Can you make 102 using 5 cube numbers?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

I've been trying to make numbers using only 5 cube numbers, the operations +,-,×,÷ and brackets. I got till 102 but I couldn't find any solution for it. I hope someone else might be able to do it.

Comment: $x = \frac{(12x+2)^3-(12x+1)^3-(12x-1)^3+(12x-2)^3}{6^3}$